# Android - Retrieving large text file from webserver

Tags: android, large-data

I have a service that does an URL call on a separate thread, and gets as result a fairly large text file ~1MB.

```
          try
            {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpMethod = new HttpGet("www.example.com");
            httpMethod.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response = client.execute(httpMethod, responseHandler);
            result = response.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
```

I then do some processing, store the result in a singleton, and send a broadcast to notify an Activity that i have the data ready. The problem is the data in the singleton doesn't seem to get updated. Any ideas? Is there a better way i should be doing this?

Comment: Show us where and how do you update you Singleton. It would be nice if you show us also the code of the Singleton

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpResponse response =client.execute(httpMethod);
String resultBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```